# Symfony 2 - FormView::setRendered opposite

Tags: symfony, twig

FormView exposes setRendered method which tells Twig that field was already rendered. It's useful for hiding a field from form_rest.

In my case, I'd like to place form_rest before specific row - so I need to use setRendered. However I can't ressurect the row, as there is no straightfoward way to do this. Example code:

```
{% do form.frequency.setRendered %}
{{ form_rest(form) }}

{# Something like this #}
{% do form.frequency.unsetRendered %}

<div class="frequency form-group">
{{ form_row(form.frequency) }}
</div>
```

Is there something what would work like this? Or I'm left with rendering whole form by hand? FormView::rendered is private, and FormView::setRendered doesn't accept parameters. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old question, but here's one way to do it.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{# render the fields in different order, name first #}
{{ form_row(form.name) }}

{# render the the rest, except submit button #}
{% for child in form %}
    {% if child.vars.name not in ['submit'] %}
        {{ form_row(child) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# render the submit manually #}
<div class="pull-right">
    {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
</div>

{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Comment: I've used something similar then. Also, check out current best practices about buttons: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration

Answer (score 0):

No way in the current implementation of the form component :s The only solution I can see is to create a twig function which will use the reflection mechanism to modify the private property...

EDIT: Or you can submit a pull request to the Symfony repository to allow it with your usecase.